# Rails deploy to Heroku fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to push my RoR app to Heroku after a few months of not deploying anything new. I commited my changes to my local repo and tried my usual shell script deploy that calls the `git push heroku-production master`

`heroku-production`  is my git remote name for the Heroku app

I've also noticed that my Cedar version was outdated so I upgraded it to Cedar 22. After doing that I had to upgrade my Bundler too and my Ruby version. After testing it out locally I went on to deploy it to my Heroku

The deploy seems to go well until it breaks with the following messages:

```
Calling `DidYouMean::SPELL_CHECKERS.merge!(error_name => spell_checker)' has been deprecated. Please call `DidYouMean.correct_error(error_name, spell_checker)' instead.
       rake aborted!
       Could not find cache store adapter for dalli_store (cannot load such file -- active_support/cache/dalli_store)
```

and

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Here's the whole trace

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/ruby
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 2.3.25
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
###### WARNING:
       Your app was upgraded to bundler 2.3.25.
       Previously you had a successful deploy with bundler 1.15.2.
       
       If you see problems related to the bundler version please refer to:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#known-upgrade-issues
       
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-3.1.2
       Purging Cache. Changing stack from cedar-14 to heroku-22
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.3.25
       Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching rake 13.0.6
       Installing rake 13.0.6
       Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
       Fetching builder 3.2.4
       Fetching minitest 5.15.0
       Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
       Installing builder 3.2.4
       Installing minitest 5.15.0
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
       Fetching erubis 2.7.0
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Using racc 1.6.0
       Fetching crass 1.0.6
       Fetching rack 2.2.3
       Installing crass 1.0.6
       Fetching nio4r 2.5.8
       Installing nio4r 2.5.8 with native extensions
       Installing rack 2.2.3
       Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.5
       Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.5
       Fetching mini_mime 1.1.2
       Fetching jsonapi-renderer 0.2.2
       Installing mini_mime 1.1.2
       Installing jsonapi-renderer 0.2.2
       Fetching arel 7.1.4
       Fetching public_suffix 4.0.6
       Installing arel 7.1.4
       Installing public_suffix 4.0.6
       Fetching bcrypt 3.1.16
       Fetching coderay 1.1.3
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.16 with native extensions
       Fetching erubi 1.10.0
       Installing erubi 1.10.0
       Installing coderay 1.1.3
       Fetching debug_inspector 1.1.0
       Installing debug_inspector 1.1.0 with native extensions
       Fetching thor 0.20.3
       Installing thor 0.20.3
       Fetching method_source 1.0.0
       Installing method_source 1.0.0
       Using bundler 2.3.25
       Fetching climate_control 0.2.0
       Installing climate_control 0.2.0
       Fetching orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Fetching execjs 2.8.1
       Installing execjs 2.8.1
       Fetching connection_pool 2.2.5
       Installing connection_pool 2.2.5
       Fetching dalli 3.2.3
       Installing dalli 3.2.3
       Fetching ffi 1.15.5
       Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions
       Fetching foreman 0.87.2
       Installing foreman 0.87.2
       Fetching geocoder 1.7.3
       Installing geocoder 1.7.3
       Fetching multi_json 1.15.0
       Installing multi_json 1.15.0
       Fetching tilt 2.0.10
       Installing tilt 2.0.10
       Fetching sexp_processor 4.16.0
       Installing sexp_processor 4.16.0
       Fetching htmlentities 4.3.4
       Installing htmlentities 4.3.4
       Fetching mime-types-data 3.2022.0105
       Installing mime-types-data 3.2022.0105
       Fetching multi_xml 0.6.0
       Installing multi_xml 0.6.0
       Fetching memcached 1.8.0
       Installing memcached 1.8.0 with native extensions
       Fetching rb-fsevent 0.11.1
       Installing rb-fsevent 0.11.1
       Fetching select2-rails 3.5.11
       Installing select2-rails 3.5.11
       Fetching truncate_html 0.9.3
       Installing truncate_html 0.9.3
       Fetching newrelic_rpm 8.4.0
       Installing newrelic_rpm 8.4.0
       Fetching oj 3.13.11
       Installing oj 3.13.11 with native extensions
       Fetching pg 1.3.2
       Installing pg 1.3.2 with native extensions
       Fetching puma 3.12.6
       Installing puma 3.12.6 with native extensions
       Fetching redis 4.6.0
       Installing redis 4.6.0
       Fetching rolify 6.0.0
       Installing rolify 6.0.0
       Fetching rollbar 3.3.0
       Installing rollbar 3.3.0
       Fetching will_paginate 3.1.8
       Installing will_paginate 3.1.8
       Fetching nokogiri 1.13.1 (x86_64-linux)
       Installing nokogiri 1.13.1 (x86_64-linux)
       Fetching tzinfo 1.2.9
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.9
       Fetching i18n 1.10.0
       Installing i18n 1.10.0
       Fetching websocket-driver 0.6.5
       Installing websocket-driver 0.6.5 with native extensions
       Fetching rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Fetching warden 1.2.9
       Installing warden 1.2.9
       Fetching request_store 1.5.1
       Installing request_store 1.5.1
       Fetching sprockets 3.7.2
       Installing sprockets 3.7.2
       Fetching mail 2.7.1
       Installing mail 2.7.1
       Fetching addressable 2.8.0
       Installing addressable 2.8.0
       Fetching better_errors 2.9.1
       Installing better_errors 2.9.1
       Fetching bitters 2.0.3
       Installing bitters 2.0.3
       Fetching bourbon 6.0.0
       Installing bourbon 6.0.0
       Fetching neat 4.0.0
       Installing neat 4.0.0
       Fetching pry 0.14.1
       Installing pry 0.14.1
       Fetching terrapin 0.6.0
       Installing terrapin 0.6.0
       Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Fetching uglifier 4.2.0
       Installing uglifier 4.2.0
       Fetching binding_of_caller 1.0.0
       Installing binding_of_caller 1.0.0
       Fetching haml 4.0.7
       Installing haml 4.0.7
       Fetching ruby_parser 3.18.1
       Installing ruby_parser 3.18.1
       Fetching mime-types 3.4.1
       Installing mime-types 3.4.1
       Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.1
       Installing rb-inotify 0.10.1
       Fetching sidekiq 6.4.1
       Installing sidekiq 6.4.1
       Fetching loofah 2.14.0
       Installing loofah 2.14.0
       Fetching activesupport 5.0.7.2
       Installing activesupport 5.0.7.2
       Fetching money 6.16.0
       Installing money 6.16.0
       Fetching css_parser 1.11.0
       Installing css_parser 1.11.0
       Fetching cocaine 0.6.0
       Installing cocaine 0.6.0
       Fetching html2haml 2.2.0
       Installing html2haml 2.2.0
       Fetching httparty 0.20.0
       Installing httparty 0.20.0
       Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
       Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
       Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
       Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Fetching globalid 1.0.0
       Installing globalid 1.0.0
       Fetching activemodel 5.0.7.2
       Installing activemodel 5.0.7.2
       Fetching case_transform 0.2
       Installing case_transform 0.2
       Fetching intercom-rails 0.4.2
       Installing intercom-rails 0.4.2
       Fetching pundit 2.2.0
       Installing pundit 2.2.0
       Fetching monetize 1.12.0
       Installing monetize 1.12.0
       Fetching premailer 1.15.0
       Installing premailer 1.15.0
       Fetching ckeditor 4.1.6
       Installing ckeditor 4.1.6
       Fetching sass 3.7.4
       Installing sass 3.7.4
       Fetching actionview 5.0.7.2
       Installing actionview 5.0.7.2
       Fetching activejob 5.0.7.2
       Installing activejob 5.0.7.2
       Fetching activerecord 5.0.7.2
       Installing activerecord 5.0.7.2
       Fetching actionpack 5.0.7.2
       Fetching jbuilder 2.11.5
       Installing actionpack 5.0.7.2
       Installing jbuilder 2.11.5
       Fetching annotate 3.2.0
       Installing annotate 3.2.0
       Fetching friendly_id 5.1.0
       Fetching actioncable 5.0.7.2
       Installing friendly_id 5.1.0
       Installing actioncable 5.0.7.2
       Fetching actionmailer 5.0.7.2
       Fetching active_model_serializers 0.10.13
       Installing actionmailer 5.0.7.2
       Installing active_model_serializers 0.10.13
       Fetching railties 5.0.7.2
       Fetching gon 6.4.0
       Installing railties 5.0.7.2
       Installing gon 6.4.0
       Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.2
       Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.2
       Fetching premailer-rails 1.11.1
       Installing premailer-rails 1.11.1
       Fetching breadcrumbs_on_rails 4.1.0
       Fetching coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Installing breadcrumbs_on_rails 4.1.0
       Installing coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Fetching haml-rails 0.9.0
       Fetching responders 2.1.2
       Installing haml-rails 0.9.0
       Installing responders 2.1.2
       Fetching money-rails 1.15.0
       Fetching jquery-rails 4.4.0
       Installing money-rails 1.15.0
       Installing jquery-rails 4.4.0
       Fetching rails 5.0.7.2
       Installing rails 5.0.7.2
       Fetching rails-i18n 5.1.3
       Fetching sass-rails 5.0.7
       Installing sass-rails 5.0.7
       Fetching devise 4.8.1
       Installing rails-i18n 5.1.3
       Installing devise 4.8.1
       Fetching devise-i18n 1.10.1
       Installing devise-i18n 1.10.1
       Fetching monologue 0.5.0
       Installing monologue 0.5.0
       Bundle complete! 51 Gemfile dependencies, 118 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
       Post-install message from haml:
       
       HEADS UP! Haml 4.0 has many improvements, but also has changes that may break
       your application:
       
       * Support for Ruby 1.8.6 dropped
       * Support for Rails 2 dropped
       * Sass filter now always outputs <style> tags
       * Data attributes are now hyphenated, not underscored
       * html2haml utility moved to the html2haml gem
       * Textile and Maruku filters moved to the haml-contrib gem
       
       For more info see:
       
       http://rubydoc.info/github/haml/haml/file/CHANGELOG.md
       
       Post-install message from httparty:
       When you HTTParty, you must party hard!
       Post-install message from sass:
       
       Ruby Sass has reached end-of-life and should no longer be used.
       
       * If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
         primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install
       
       * If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
         sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme
       
       * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
         https://sass-lang.com/blog/posts/7828841
       
       Bundle completed (62.09s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v16.13.1-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Calling `DidYouMean::SPELL_CHECKERS.merge!(error_name => spell_checker)' has been deprecated. Please call `DidYouMean.correct_error(error_name, spell_checker)' instead.
       rake aborted!
       Could not find cache store adapter for dalli_store (cannot load such file -- active_support/cache/dalli_store)
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/cache.rb:106:in `rescue in retrieve_store_class'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/cache.rb:103:in `retrieve_store_class'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/cache.rb:60:in `lookup_store'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:64:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/config/environment.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       
       Caused by:
       LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_support/cache/dalli_store
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/cache.rb:104:in `retrieve_store_class'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/cache.rb:60:in `lookup_store'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:64:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/config/environment.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_1e810a44/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to subasteo-eu-production.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/subasteo-eu-production.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/subasteo-eu-production.git'
```

I've tried Googling around the fixes to no avail...

I tried changing my Gemfile and updading the Dalli, I added `gem 'memcached'`to the Gemfile too, but that didn't fix the problem

Here is my Gemfile.lock too if it helps:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.0.7.2)
      actionpack (= 5.0.7.2)
      nio4r (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.0.7.2)
      actionpack (= 5.0.7.2)
      actionview (= 5.0.7.2)
      activejob (= 5.0.7.2)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.0.7.2)
      actionview (= 5.0.7.2)
      activesupport (= 5.0.7.2)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.0.7.2)
      activesupport (= 5.0.7.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    active_model_serializers (0.10.13)
      actionpack (>= 4.1, < 7.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.1, < 7.1)
      case_transform (>= 0.2)
      jsonapi-renderer (>= 0.1.1.beta1, < 0.3)
    activejob (5.0.7.2)
      activesupport (= 5.0.7.2)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.0.7.2)
      activesupport (= 5.0.7.2)
    activerecord (5.0.7.2)
      activemodel (= 5.0.7.2)
      activesupport (= 5.0.7.2)
      arel (~> 7.0)
    activesupport (5.0.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.8.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    annotate (3.2.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.2, < 8.0)
      rake (>= 10.4, < 14.0)
    arel (7.1.4)
    bcrypt (3.1.16)
    better_errors (2.9.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubi (>= 1.0.0)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    binding_of_caller (1.0.0)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bitters (2.0.3)
      thor (~> 0.19)
    bourbon (6.0.0)
      thor (~> 0.19)
    breadcrumbs_on_rails (4.1.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    bullet (7.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      uniform_notifier (~> 1.11)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    case_transform (0.2)
      activesupport
    ckeditor (4.1.6)
      cocaine
      orm_adapter (~> 0.5.0)
    climate_control (0.2.0)
    cocaine (0.6.0)
      terrapin (= 0.6.0)
    coderay (1.1.3)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
    connection_pool (2.2.5)
    crass (1.0.6)
    css_parser (1.11.0)
      addressable
    dalli (3.2.3)
    debug_inspector (1.1.0)
    devise (4.8.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise-i18n (1.10.1)
      devise (>= 4.8.0)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.8.1)
    ffi (1.15.5)
    foreman (0.87.2)
    friendly_id (5.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    geocoder (1.7.3)
    globalid (1.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    gon (6.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.20)
      i18n (>= 0.7)
      multi_json
      request_store (>= 1.0)
    haml (4.0.7)
      tilt
    haml-rails (0.9.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.1)
      haml (>= 4.0.6, < 5.0)
      html2haml (>= 1.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.1)
    html2haml (2.2.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      haml (>= 4.0, < 6)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.5)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    httparty (0.20.0)
      mime-types (~> 3.0)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (1.10.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    intercom-rails (0.4.2)
      activesupport (> 3.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.5)
      actionview (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jquery-rails (4.4.0)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jsonapi-renderer (0.2.2)
    launchy (2.5.0)
      addressable (~> 2.7)
    letter_opener (1.7.0)
      launchy (~> 2.2)
    listen (3.0.8)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    loofah (2.14.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    memcached (1.8.0)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mime-types (3.4.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2022.0105)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    minitest (5.15.0)
    monetize (1.12.0)
      money (~> 6.12)
    money (6.16.0)
      i18n (>= 0.6.4, <= 2)
    money-rails (1.15.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      monetize (~> 1.9)
      money (~> 6.13)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    monologue (0.5.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.1.7)
      ckeditor (~> 4.1.1)
      coffee-rails (>= 4.0.0)
      jquery-rails
      rails (>= 4.0.4)
      rails-i18n
      responders (~> 2.1.0)
      sass-rails (~> 5.0.0)
      select2-rails (~> 3.2)
      truncate_html
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    neat (4.0.0)
      thor (~> 0.19)
    newrelic_rpm (8.4.0)
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.13.1-x86_64-darwin)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    nokogiri (1.13.1-x86_64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    oj (3.13.11)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (1.3.2)
    premailer (1.15.0)
      addressable
      css_parser (>= 1.6.0)
      htmlentities (>= 4.0.0)
    premailer-rails (1.11.1)
      actionmailer (>= 3)
      premailer (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.9)
    pry (0.14.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (3.12.6)
    pundit (2.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    racc (1.6.0)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (5.0.7.2)
      actioncable (= 5.0.7.2)
      actionmailer (= 5.0.7.2)
      actionpack (= 5.0.7.2)
      actionview (= 5.0.7.2)
      activejob (= 5.0.7.2)
      activemodel (= 5.0.7.2)
      activerecord (= 5.0.7.2)
      activesupport (= 5.0.7.2)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.0.7.2)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.2)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    rails-i18n (5.1.3)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      railties (>= 5.0, < 6)
    railties (5.0.7.2)
      actionpack (= 5.0.7.2)
      activesupport (= 5.0.7.2)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.6)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.1)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    redis (4.6.0)
    request_store (1.5.1)
      rack (>= 1.4)
    responders (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
    rolify (6.0.0)
    rollbar (3.3.0)
    ruby_parser (3.18.1)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.16)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    select2-rails (3.5.11)
    sexp_processor (4.16.0)
    sidekiq (6.4.1)
      connection_pool (>= 2.2.2)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      redis (>= 4.2.0)
    spring (2.1.1)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    terrapin (0.6.0)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    truncate_html (0.9.3)
    tzinfo (1.2.9)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    uniform_notifier (1.14.2)
    warden (1.2.9)
      rack (>= 2.0.9)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.6.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    will_paginate (3.1.8)
    xray-rails (0.3.2)
      rails (>= 3.1.0)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-20
  x86_64-darwin-21
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  active_model_serializers (~> 0.10.0)
  annotate
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  bitters
  bourbon
  breadcrumbs_on_rails
  bullet
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  dalli
  devise
  devise-i18n
  foreman
  friendly_id (~> 5.1.0)
  geocoder
  gon
  haml
  haml-rails (~> 0.9)
  httparty
  intercom-rails
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  letter_opener
  listen (~> 3.0.5)
  memcached
  monetize
  money
  money-rails
  monologue (~> 0.5.0)
  neat
  newrelic_rpm
  nokogiri
  oj
  pg
  premailer-rails
  pry
  puma (~> 3.0)
  pundit
  rails (~> 5.0.0, >= 5.0.0.1)
  rolify
  rollbar
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sidekiq
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console
  will_paginate (~> 3.1.0)
  xray-rails

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.1.2p20

BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.7
```

**UPDATE**

Here's my production.rb and the staging.rb. I checked the API keys / credentials and they're correct

```
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store,
                    (ENV["MEMCACHIER_SERVERS"] || "").split(","),
                    {:username => ENV["MEMCACHIER_USERNAME"],
                     :password => ENV["MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD"],
                     :failover => true,
                     :socket_timeout => 1.5,
                     :socket_failure_delay => 0.2,
                     :down_retry_delay => 60
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your `config.cache_store` setting in `config/environments/production.rb` ... it should be this:

```rb
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
```